# How to create a new project/module in IntelliJ from CVS?

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

In Eclipse, a new project may be created from a CVS project in this way:

```
 File > New > Project..., then select the wizard CVS > projects from CVS.
```

It also possible to select certain tag/branch for the new project.

How can I do the same in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if there is a quicker way to do it, but I would do it like this (2 ways), either:

- create the project root in svn via some other method (e.g. a tool similar to TortoiseSVN), and check it out in IntelliJ via `VCS` -> `Checkout from Version Control`
- create a new intellij project (use the proper format, e.g. Maven Module), and check it in via `VCS` -> `Import into Version Control`

Now that you have asked this question, I realize that this is a somewhat 'clunky' 2-step process in an otherwise very usable IDE.

And you can sometimes screw it up by checking out or importing out from / to the wrong point (ever ended up with `c:\myproject\trunk\trunk` ?)

There's every chance that I missed something, but otherwise I think this a *Create New Project in VCS Wizard* would be a fine feature request for the JetBrains people.!

So thanks for asking the question, upvoted.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am transferring form Eclipse to IntelliJ due to the bad performance of Eclipse. But I miss some handy and convenient features of Eclipse and cannot find their equivalences in IntelliJ.